# Why does CDC::SelectObject(CFont*) accept a CFont object vs. a pointer?

Tags: c++, mfc

```
    CPaintDC dc(this); 
    CFont font; 
    dc.SelectObject(font);  // why does this build?
```

The function [CDC::SelectObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/715b3334-cb2b-4c9c-8067-02eb7c66c8b2.aspx#cdc__selectobject) takes a pointer of type `CFont` but why does this build with providing an object? I came across this issue that the above code is unpredictable and can crash sometimes but not always.

Comment: Because of `CFont::operator HFONT() const;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code in question is valid, sort of. It compiles due to a combination of two things:

- The [`CFont::operator HFONT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfont-class#operator_hfont).
- An **undocumented** [`CDC::SelectObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class) overload taking an `HGDIOBJ` handle.

When the compiler tries to match an overload for `dc.SelectObject(font)`, none of them match. So next it tries the user-defined conversion operator (`operator HFONT()`) that returns an `HFONT`. That matches the undocumented overload taking an `HGDIOBJ` (both `HGDIOBJ` and `HFONT` are typedef'd as `void*`).

The code posted in the question is almost correct, too, with 2 exceptions:

- The `font` object is destroyed while still being selected into a device context. While this causes a double-delete bug (the font object is owned by the `CFont` instance and the device context), the call to [`DeleteFont`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183535.aspx) gracefully fails when passed an invalid handle.
- The font object previously selected into the device context is lost, and thereby leaked.

Neither issue causes unpredictable behavior or intermittent crashes. As explained in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833811/1889329), the real code, however, looks like this:

```
CFont* pOldFont = (CFont*) dc.SelectObject(font);
```

That is a bug that exhibits undefined behavior. `dc.SelectObject(font)` returns an `HGDIOBJ` (typedef'd as `void*`), which is subsequently cast to an unrelated type (`CFont*`). While storing the font previously selected into the device context to later restore it is correct, the code is not. An implementation that honors ownership could be:

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
CFont font;
CFont oldFont;
// Transfer ownership of font to the DC, and the previously selected font into oldFont
oldFont.Attach(dc.SelectObject(font.Detach()));

// Use dc

// Transfer ownership back
font.Attach(dc.SelectObject(oldFont.Detach()));

// oldFont goes out of scope; this a no-op since it no longer owns any resources
// font goes out of scope, releasing all resources owned by it
// dc goes out of scope, releasing all resources owned by objects selected into it
```

If you are willing to temporarily sacrifice strict ownership semantics, you can make your life easier by using the more standard implementation:

```
CPaintDC dc(this); 
CFont font; 
CFont* pOldFont = dc.SelectObject(&font);

// Use dc

dc.SelectObject(pOldFont);
```

This is safe, even if you exit early, without restoring the device context. It would still lead to a double-delete on the font object owned by both the `CFont` instance and the device context (which is handled gracefully by the API). It doesn't exhibit a font leak, though, because things are more complicated than it seems: There is another invisible owner involved here, a map controlled by MFC that stores temporary objects (like those returned from [`CGdiObject::FromHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cgdiobject-class#fromhandle), which `SelectObject(CFont*)` calls). The temporary objects are cleaned up as part of MFC's idle time processing.

Comment: That seems a better explanation. I was going to add my own answer along the same lines with code example how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with answer by IInspectable and here is my own proof of concept how this works:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class A {
    int a_int = 6;
    char* a_carp = "A derived";
public:
    operator int() { return a_int; }
    operator char*() { return a_carp; }
};

class B : public A {
    float b_float = 5.7;
    char* b_carp = "B Derived";
public:
    operator float() { return b_float; }
    operator char*() { return b_carp; }
};

void Print(char * text)
{
    std::cout << text << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    B b_obj;
    //  long a = b_obj;
    char* c_p = b_obj;

    Print(b_obj);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code builds and the output is "B Derived".

**How does it works?**

When we use an object in place of a different type, the object looks for appropriate conversion operator. If it finds it, it applies it and converts that for you.

In this case, that operator was `HFONT()`. It is important to note the actual name of the operator doesn't matter, its the return type/signature that matters. So when it finds a match (correct signature), it calls it.

**Why unpredictable behavior?**

Let me clear that as well since I mention that in OP. The code I posted was related to build issue but the actual code was this:

```
CFont* pOldFont = (CFont*) dc.SelectObject(font);
```

And the forced typecasting `(CFont*)` was the problem. If we pass `HGDIOBJ` to `SelectObject()`, it returns `HGDIOBJ` but it was forced typecasted to `CFont *` and that was the problem so there is nothing else wrong with using conversion operators.

Comment: That's not, what actually happens, though. MFC is a C++ library, but the issue is not about class hierarchies. It's about `CDC`'s exposure of the underlying C interface, and there are no class hierarchies in C. It provides a `SelectObject` overload, taking an `HGDIOBJ`. `HGDIOBJ` and `HFONT` are different names for the same underlying type.

Comment: @IInspectable The class hierarchy I have shown just adds more details whose object's type conversion gets called but I am sure it is a class thing.

Comment: The typecast isn't present in your question. The code in your question is (almost) correct, with the exception of destroying an object while it is still selected into a DC. You have to select the old font into the DC before `font` goes out of scope. To fix this code, you could simply store the `HGDIOBJ` returned from `SelectObject`, or attach it to another `CFont` instance: `CFont oldFont; oldFont.Attach(dc.SelectObject(font)); ... dc.SelectObject(oldFont.Detach();`.